# up-to-date gems for csv export

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm looking for some up to date rubygem to export file to csv format. i'm aware of [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/362-exporting-csv-and-excel) solution, but looking for some other ways. maybe even some gems fresh enough for Rails 4?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby CSV class is usually enough:

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html